# error code with Silhouette graph in r code

Tags: r, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, k-means, data-analysis

*I have writen a code to use k means clustering on cell data, and return the optimal amount of clusters per cell type. I am trying to code in a Silhouette graph in order to check my results, however every time i run my code i get an error stating: **Error in round(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function.** I have tried changing various variables but am completely stumped.*

```
e
library(NbClust)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggthemes)
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
library(cluster)


#/////////////////////////////////////

df = read.csv("C:/Users/chelsie/desktop/itoresults.csv")
df = df[,-1]

###################### Elbow Method

#Elbow Method for finding the optimal number of clusters
set.seed(123)
# Compute and plot wss for k
k <- 15
data <- df[2:3]
wss <- sapply(1:k, function(k){kmeans(data, k, nstart=50,iter.max = 15 
)$tot.withinss})

# normalize and plot wss f
normal_wss = wss/sum(wss)

# to find the optimal clustering count
elbow_optimal_num <- 0
m_sum_wss = 0
for (val in normal_wss) {
  if(m_sum_wss <0.65)  
  {
    m_sum_wss=m_sum_wss+val
    elbow_optimal_num = elbow_optimal_num+1
  }
}

# display the result
fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "wss") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = elbow_optimal_num, linetype = 2)+
  labs(subtitle = "Elbow method")




###################### Clustering Script
clusters <- kmeans(df[2:3], k)

# Save the cluster number in the dataset as column 'Borough'
df$clusterId <- as.factor(clusters$cluster)
m_color=c("#999999","#E69F00","#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", 
"#D55E00", "#CC79A7","#A09999","#B99F00","#E6E4E9", "#777E73", "#D1A142", 
"#33AAB2", "#99CC00")

fviz_cluster(clusters, data = df[2:3], 
             ellipse.type = "norm",
             ellipse.level = 0.99,
             palette = m_color,
             geom = "point",
             axes = c(0,0), 
             show.clust.cent = TRUE,
             ggtheme = theme_minimal()
             )

clusters$totss
clusters$size
clusters$centers
clusters$tot.withinss
clusters$withinss
clusters$cluster
clusters$betweenss


plot(silhouette(clusters), col=1:8, border=NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "elbow" method is not looking for any elbow. Instead is an incorrect (!) attempt to use the common PCA heuristic of "explained variance". Except that your normalization is wrong - it normalized with the sum of variances for different k, instead you should be normalizing with the total SSQ (for k=1, technically). By taking the sum, your normalization term depends on your choice of the range of is to try. Neither is the Elbow method though. The Elbow method is a *visual* inspection where the experienced user can pick a good k (and the more experienced user will also decide that there might be no good k at all, and preprocessing needs to be improved). The Elbow method is *not* automatic.

You can also stop earlier then: determine the total SSQ, multiply it with the desired reduction of, e.g., 0.65. Then begin with k=2 and stop once the SSQ is low enough - no need to try all k!

Except that this also doesn't make much sense if you intend to use Silhouette afterwards. Then you should rather pick the "optimal" (it's not optimal, all these are just heuristics!) k using Silhouette instead of SSQ theshold.

As for Silhouette, it will need both a distance matrix and the cluster labels. So you will likely need to invoke it differently.